# Can i access internal memory of Application of A using another apllication B?

Tags: java, android

I have two applications.

Application - A and Application - B

Application - A download songs from the server and stored into the internal memory . I want to read those download files using Application - B.

Is it possible ? If yes then how can i do this ?

Thanks In Advace.

Answer (score 2):

a) if you make them readable to all applications

b) if both applications are signed by you and you set them to have a shared userid, then they can share private storage

c) if you make them readable to all applications but encrypt them in a way that you hope only your two apps can decode (but then you can't just hand them off to the framework to play)

Remember that a rooted device is an open book though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to xchange stuff from one app to the other you have to use a content provider. Build one with a sqlite db and insert your songs with the BLOB datatype.
Never tried this, but it could work.